# Identify plant with white flowers and prickly fruit

Tags: identification

I have a certain plant in my garden, but I didn't plant it.
It has white flowers, and is bearing some kind of prickly fruits.

Can someone tell me which plant this might be?

Thanks a lot!

[Picture 1](https://ibb.co/gxu04T)
[Picture 2](https://ibb.co/cCaUyo)
[Picture 3](https://ibb.co/nCgcJo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Jimsonweed (*[Datura stramonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura_stramonium)*). It is a fairly common weed of recently turned ground in North America. Children and others should be warned not to mess with the fruits or the plant in general, should be taught what the plant looks like and to pass on the message to others. Please read what the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura_stramonium) says and do further reading. Thanks.

Comment: Snap! there was nothing posted before I typed my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It is Datura stramonium, also known as Jimson Weed. If you have children who might eat parts of the plant or the seedpods and seeds later on, you might want to remove it - all parts are toxic, but only if you eat it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura_stramonium

Comment: Sorry, I awarded the "correct" answer to the one answered first :-|. I can't award it to both :-). But thanks a lot!!